# accessing atributes of a service in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I created a service to share some data between two controllers. The thing is that this controllers set and get some data from this service. But I don't know why when I try to get data, all this variables are not set.

My code is this one:

```
 var appModule = angular.module('app', ['mgcrea.ngStrap'])
            // custom service to share/collect data between controllers
            // this objects are populated by the controllers
            .service('sharedProperties', function () {
                    this.searchPattern = {
                                        basicFilters: {},
                                        advanceFilters: {}
                                    };

            });

    // controller for main section
    appModule.controller('parentController', function ($scope, $aside, sharedProperties) {
        $scope.basicFilters = {
                                category: 'undef',
                                masterbrand: {value:'undef', text: 'Any'},
                                page: 1,
                                perPage:10,
                                q:''
                            };

        // populate object in service 
        $scope.updatePatternSearch = function(newValue, oldValue, scope) {
            sharedProperties.searchPattern.basicFilters = 'HI!, I have a value!';
        };
        $scope.$watch('basicFilters', 'updatePatternSearch', true);

        // get variables from service
        $scope.search = function() {
                // ** PROBLEM ** 
                // firebug says that is:basicFilters: {},
                //                      advanceFilters: {}
                // empties????, why??
                console.log(sharedProperties.searchPattern); 
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you put it in a plnkr of fiddle please

Comment: Pretty ugly code.  Try to structure it better.  Inject your service into your controller, create a "get" method on your service then from your controller call sharedProperties.get<whatever>

Comment: yes, I'm doing it. I dont know why the variable from the controller in plnkr is not being printed correctly...
http://plnkr.co/edit/4e63PRF4KyLcvPvr36eJ?p=preview

Comment: I did it, this ugly code is just trying to simplify the code. The original has more stuff as you said. But this is the most basic I can get it and is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of typos and erros in your plnkr code.

I have forked and updated it. It's working fine.

Have a look at this - http://plnkr.co/edit/BVFjufOQFFlhB2gTqIeB?p=preview

Comment: I saw it right now....I rewrote my code a little, and should be that because now is working. I'll have a look into that, I spent long time....Thanks.